# Why does this expected value simplify as shown?

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, probability

I was reading about the german tank problem and they say that in a sample of size $k$, from a population of integers from $1,\ldots,N$ the probability that the sample maximum equals $m$ is:

$$\frac{\binom{m-1}{k-1}}{\binom{N}{k}}$$

This make sense. But then they take expected value of the sample maximum and claim:

$$\mu = \sum_{m=k}^N m \frac{\binom{m-1}{k-1}}{\binom{N}{k}} = \frac{k(N+1)}{k+1}$$

And I don't quite see how to simplify that summation. I can pull out the denominator and a $(k-1)!$ term out and get:

$$\mu = \frac{(k-1)!}{\binom{N}{k}} \sum_{m=k}^N m(m-1) \ldots (m-k+1)$$

But I get stuck there...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call $B_k^N=\sum\limits_{m=k}^N\binom{m-1}{k-1}$.

---

> **Fact 1:** $B_k^N=\binom{N}{k}$ (because the sum of the masses of a discrete probability measure is $1$ or by a direct computation).

---

> **Fact 2:** For every $n\geqslant i\geqslant 1$, $n\binom{n-1}{i-1}=i\binom{n}{i}$.

---

Now to the proof.

Fact 2 for $(n,i)=(m,k)$ gives $\sum\limits_{m=k}^Nm\binom{m-1}{k-1}=\sum\limits_{m=k}^Nk\binom{m}{k}=k\sum\limits_{m=k+1}^{N+1}\binom{m-1}{(k+1)-1}=kB_{k+1}^{N+1}$.

Fact 1 gives $B_{k+1}^{N+1}=\binom{N+1}{k+1}$.

Fact 2 for $(n,i)=(N+1,k+1)$ (or a direct computation) gives $(k+1)B_{k+1}^{N+1}=(N+1)B_k^N$.

Finally, $\mu=\dfrac{kB_{k+1}^{N+1}}{B_k^N}=k\dfrac{N+1}{k+1}$.

---

**Edit** The same method yields, for every $i\geqslant0$,
$$
\mathrm E(X(X+1)\cdots(X+i))=\frac{k}{k+i+1}(N+1)(N+2)\cdots(N+i+1).
$$

Comment: Wow that is an elegant and slick solution. Thanks!

Comment: +1 I love it when you can bootstrap a formula derived probabilistically into a related formula for expectation.

Answer (score 9):

Here is another way of looking at the problem that uses the natural symmetry.

The samples of size $k$ are in one-to-one correspondence
with the sequence of "gaps" between the observations 
(via the sequence of order statistics):

$$\{x_1,x_2,\dots, x_k\}\leftrightarrow x_{(1)}<x_{(2)}<\cdots <x_{(k)}
\leftrightarrow (G_1,G_2,\dots, G_{k+1})$$

Here we define $G_1=x_{(1)}$, $G_j=x_{(j)}-x_{(j-1)}$ for $2\leq j\leq k$,
  and $G_{k+1}=(N+1)-x_{(k)}$. This 
correspondence shows that $G_1,G_2,\dots, G_{k+1}$ are 
exchangeable random variables, in particular, they are identically distributed.

Since 
$\sum_{j=1}^{k+1} G_j=N+1$ 
**identically**,  the  expectations of these $k+1$ identically distributed
random variables must be $\mathbb{E}(G_j)={N+1\over k+1}$.

In particular, $\mathbb{E}(G_{k+1})=\mathbb{E}((N+1)-x_{(k)})={N+1\over k+1}$
which implies 
$$\mathbb{E}(\mbox{Maximum})=\mathbb{E}(x_{(k)})=(N+1)- {N+1\over k+1}={k\over k+1} (N+1).$$

Similarly, we see that the expected values of the order statistics $\mathbb{E}(x_{(1)}),\mathbb{E}(x_{(2)}),\dots, 
\mathbb{E}(x_{(k)})$ are evenly spread out from ${1\over k+1} (N+1)$
 to ${k\over k+1} (N+1).$

See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66430/what-is-the-distribution-of-gaps) for more questions about these gaps.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, $$\mu = \sum_{m=k}^N m \frac{\binom{m-1}{k-1}}{\binom{N}{k}}
= \sum_{m=k}^{N}\frac{m! k!(N-k)!}{N!(k-1)!(m-k)!}$$
$$= k\frac{k! (N-k)!}{N!} \sum_{m=k}^N \binom{m}{m-k}
= k\frac{k! (N-k)!}{N!} \binom{N+1}{N-k}$$
$$= k\frac{k! (N-k)! (N+1)}{N! (N-k)! (k+1)!} = k\frac{N+1}{k+1}$$

where
$$\sum_{m=k}^N \binom{m}{m-k} = \sum_{i=0}^{N-k} \binom{k+i}{i} = \binom{N+1}{N-k}$$
can be seen from Pascal's Triangle.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$\mu = \sum_{m=k}^N m \frac{\binom{m-1}{k-1}}{\binom{N}{k}}$$
$$= \sum_{m=k}^{N}m \frac{(m-1)! k!(N-k)!}{N!(k-1)!(m-k)!}$$

$$= \frac{k!(N-k)!}{N!(k-1)!} \sum_{m=k}^{N} m \frac{(m-1)!}{(m-k)!}$$

$$ = \frac{k (N-k)!}{N!} \sum_{m=k}^{N} \frac{m!}{(m-k)!}$$

The expression on the right is a [sum of falling factorials](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/rapportBIPM/1995/01.pdf).