# Average Number of PIN Code Attempts

Tags: combinatorics

If I want the *average* number of PIN code attempts for a PIN of length 4 using the numbers 0-9, would I have to half my answer? So $10^4 = 10 000$ possible combinations, but the average number of attempts needed to guess correctly would be  $5 000$?

Comment: Are the successive failures leading to an ultimate success coordinated?  Would a failed attempt be repeated?

Comment: Are you essentially asking how many different guesses are required in order for the probability to be .5 that you have guessed the correct PIN?

Comment: None of the answers have appropriate justification. Consider this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206798/pulling-cards-from-a-deck-without-replacement-to-reach-a-goal-average-draws-nee

Comment: It should probably be noted that in practice you can expect to only have to guess about $1800$ times per PIN in the long run, with a typical number of guesses around $400$ and the most likely number of guesses being $1$.
https://www.datagenetics.com/blog/september32012/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correct in interpreting the problem as how many different attempts are required in order that the probability is $1/2$ that you will have guess the correct PIN, then your answer of $5000$ attempts is correct, as you would multiply the probability of guessing the PIN correctly on one attempt, which is $\frac{1}{10000}$ by that number $x$ whose product is $.5$; that is, we solve

$$ \frac{1}{10,000} x = .5 $$

which gives

$$ x = 5000$$

Answer (score 1):

This question can be solved by first trying it for small numbers. What if there were not 10000 possible combinations, but 1, 2, 3 or 4?

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{Combinations} & \text{Average number of attempts} \\
1 & 1 \\
2 & \frac32 \\
3 & 2 \\
4 & \frac52 \\
\dots & \dots
\end{array}
$$